# WebMvcLinkBuilder can not handle alwaysUseFullPath=true

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

I've got pretty much the same problem as in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/102 but with newer builder i.e. `WebMvcLinkBuilder`.

In short:

- the rest servlet is mapped onto `/rest/v1/*` like this:

  ```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ImportAutoConfiguration(ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class)
    public class ServletConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Bean
        public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
            return servletContext -> {
                // REST v1 servlet
                AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext restContextV2 = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
                restContextV2.register(RestConfig.class);
                ServletRegistration.Dynamic restServletV2 = servletContext.addServlet("rest", new DispatcherServlet(restContextV2));
                restServletV2.setLoadOnStartup(1);
                restServletV2.addMapping("/rest/v1/*");
            };
        }

    }
  ```
- `alwaysUseFullPath` is on in `RestConfig`
- documents controller is mapped onto `/rest/v1/documents`

Then for a post to `/rest/v1/documents` I receive a link looking like this: `http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/rest/v1/documents` (note **doubled** servlet mapping)

Link to the full example: https://github.com/artszko/spring-hateoas-links-issue

Did I misconfigure something or this is actually a bug?

Comment: Do you have some answer on that?

Comment: I do not. Created an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/1377) on the project page but no response so far. We gave up on this a while ago, and merged two apis into one.